# MySQL: Alternative to using 'NOT'

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I rewrite this code so it returns the same, but without using 'NOT' notation?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE col1 = 1
AND NOT ( col1 = col2 OR col3 = 3);
```

From what I can understand, this should be possible to do with a join function but I wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: _From what I can understand, this should be possible to do with a join function but I wasn't able to make it work._

Not quite sure about this, but joins involves at least two tables.

Comment: From what I have seen, the same table can be joined with itself by renaming it two different things, but I am not sure how it works. But it seems Barbaros Özhan have a simpler answer.

Comment: " the same table can be joined with itself ".. yes and that means it's two (or more) table. Doesn't mean that it have to be different tables then only you can perform `JOIN`. For now, maybe you don't need to use join but going forward, you'll definitely be needing it. Nevertheless, it's better [to learn about join](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dissipating **NOT** operator onto equalities(**=**) and **OR** operator, you can rewrite the statement as

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable
 WHERE col1 = 1
   AND col1 != col2 
   AND col3 != 3
```

Comment: It's called [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for those interested